# Storing point in PostGIS from web app?

Tags: postgis, node-js

I have a vectortile layer of points I added to PostGIS using `ogr2ogr`, which runs on a remote server. The points show nicely on my client in the browser. Now I would like to add a point from my clients' browser and store it in PostGIS. What tools do I need?

I find queries like:

```
UPDATE sysinst.bio SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326),26913);
```

which I understand. But how do I exactly use this query (from my browser)? My stack is `node.js` (`express.js`) based.

Comment: You will need a server in-between the web application and your database. Typically this would be a RESTful server with a POST or PUT endpoint.

Comment: You'd define a REST endpoint in your routes and execute your query via database client ([pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) is a basic client for postgres you could start with). should be straight forward if you know your way around node

Comment: ah and you need to use an [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) query to add data to a table. also, as a rule, don't define (and send to execute) queries directly from within your client JS as this can lead to serious security lacks (SQL injections)

Comment: *security leaks

Comment: Despite requesting for a node-js solution, you might still like to have a look at geoserver and its WFS-T support. If you are not very experienced with dealing with geographical data going up-and-down the server this will deal for you with security, standards, concurrency etc. Possible drawbacks: needs java, not as fast as pure node-js solution.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! Actually I am using t-rex vector tile server to serve the tiles. It provides presentation, not storage/ insert of user data. Could I just use another server next to t-rex for the 'insert' REST endpoint? So e.g. I am thinking of having t-serve present tiles, but then have express.js (with sequelize ORM => works with postgis) next to it to take care of POST/ PUT endpoint. T-rex is actually pretty great!

Comment: Mmh, as t-rex uses nickel, it might make more sense to see if nickel can take care of the post/put endpoint...!?